# How do I get the upper body to bend forward without moving the legs?

Tags: mesh

[image][image]I'm trying to get only the upper body to bend forward (towards the knees) without the legs moving. There should be about a 30 degree angle between the upper body and the knees. I tried using the bend modifier and the simple deform modifier, but I'm not sure how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Hello, are you trying to animate or just change the shape? Maybe just put the 3D cursor at the bottom of the spine and use it as transformation pivot point. You can also share your file so that we can give a try.

Comment: So far, I am just trying to change the shape of the person. I attached the .blend file. I also attached an image of what the body should be positioned like.

Answer (score 0):

Your topology is a bit messy, if you use a *Mirror* modifier, delete half of your mesh and put it above the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Now put the 3D cursor at the axis of rotation, select the body:

[image]

Select *3D Cursor* in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel:

[image]

Rotate:

[image]

Comment: To delete half of the mesh do I just take out the mirror modifier? I clicked out of the mirror modifier and then added the subdivision modifier. After that, I tried to use the 3D cursor but it wasn't rotating forward.